# Spyder returning set() even though it shouldn't

Tags: python, set, computer-science, spyder, cs50

I am attending the CS50AI Course on edX. Whilst debugging one of my assignments I noticed that one of the functions returning something incorrectly. Whilst testing in the console I found out that doing

```
print(neighbours_for_person("914612"))
```

would return `set()` instead of `{<stuff>}`.

When I tested a different function in the (same) console which also returned a set, Spyder returned `{<stuff>}` instead of `set()`. Picture: [Picture since I can't embed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etgg1.png)

The program:

```
def neighbors_for_person(person_id):
"""
Returns (movie_id, person_id) pairs for people
who starred with a given person.
"""
movie_ids = people[person_id]["movies"]
neighbors = set()
for movie_id in movie_ids:
    for person_id in movies[movie_id]["stars"]:
        neighbors.add((movie_id, person_id))
return neighbors
```

Note: This function was provided to us for the project. I did not program it. The goal is to make an algorithm that searches for links between actors if they are connected. For example, the shortest path between Jennifer Lawrence and Tom Hanks is 2: Jennifer Lawrence is connected to Kevin Bacon by both starring in “X-Men: First Class,” and Kevin Bacon is connected to Tom Hanks by both starring in “Apollo 13.”

The function would search for every person connected to a person who starred in the same movies and return it as a set.

I already tried restarting Spyder and the console to no effect.

Comment: Where are `people` and `movies` defined? Seems like you might not be getting to the `neighbors.add` because either `movie_ids` or `movies[movie_id]['stars']` is empty

Comment: It is defined before that and all of the stuff is included in the project. (All the stuff). I guarantee that they are not empty. It is project 0 degrees in the CS50AI Course on edX given by Harvard. edx.org for the whole project.